# Gem command throws runtime error mentioning missing jar every time

Tags: ruby, rubygems, jruby, snakeyaml

Any time I try to run gem command, this error appears.

```
RuntimeError: 

you might need to reinstall the gem which depends on the missing jar 

or in case there is Jars.lock then JARS_RESOLVE=true will install the missing jars

no such file to load -- org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.18/snakeyaml-1.18 (LoadError)
              do_require at /usr/share/rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.21/lib/ruby/shared/jar_dependencies.rb:289
             require_jar at /usr/share/rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.21/lib/ruby/shared/jar_dependencies.rb:208
  require_jar_with_block at /usr/share/rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.21/lib/ruby/shared/jar_dependencies.rb:0
             require_jar at /usr/share/rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.21/lib/ruby/shared/jar_dependencies.rb:207
             require_jar at /usr/share/rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.21/lib/ruby/shared/jar_dependencies.rb:298
                  (root) at /home/petr/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.21/gems/psych-2.2.4-java/lib/psych_jars.rb:5
                 require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1040
                 require at /usr/share/rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.21/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54
                  (root) at /home/petr/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.21/gems/psych-2.2.4-java/lib/psych.rb:1
                 require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1040
                 require at /usr/share/rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.21/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54
                  (root) at /home/petr/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.21/gems/psych-2.2.4-java/lib/psych.rb:5
                  (root) at /usr/share/rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.21/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems.rb:1
               load_yaml at /usr/share/rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.21/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems.rb:609
               load_file at /usr/share/rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.21/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/config_file.rb:328
              initialize at /usr/share/rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.21/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/config_file.rb:197
        do_configuration at /usr/share/rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.21/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:74
                    load at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1059
                  (root) at /usr/share/rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.21/bin/gem:4
```

I am using rvm and I have already tried to rvm implode and reinstall rvm and jruby. But this error still persists.

Any help on how to solve it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you try to export the env var `JARS_RESOLVE=true` as suggested by the error message?

Comment: I ve tried it before rvm reinstall. I ll try it again.

Comment: Did not work again.

Comment: Could you please list the steps to reproduce the issue so I can try it on my local machine?

Comment: I haven t found much information on this error anywhere, so I don t think it will be simple to reproduce. Also I am not sure what exactly caused it. 
There was a warning that was annoying `YAML safe loading is not available. Please upgrade psych to a version that supports safe loading (>= 2.0).`. So I ran  `gem install psych -v 2.2.4`, which failed, and from then on everytime I run `gem` the error mentioned in my question appears.

Comment: So basically to recap: install rvm, `rvm install jruby-1.7.21`, `gem install psych -v 2.2.4` and I should see the same error?

Comment: Yes, but it is important to note that `gem install psych -v 2.2.4`. failed.

Comment: Currently I am trying to reinstall java as well.

Comment: Reinstalling Java has fixed the problem for me. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstalling jruby and java has solved this problem.